# when setting up "Slime" in "emacs"(latest version) how do i tell it to load swank faster?

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime, sbcl, swank

the slime manual says this:
"Loading Swank faster
For SBCL, we recommend that you create a custom core file with socket support and POSIX
bindings included because those modules take the most time to load. To create such a core,
execute the following steps:

```
shell$ sbcl
*(mapc ’require ’(sb-bsd-sockets sb-posix sb-introspect sb-cltl2 asdf))
 *(save-lisp-and-die "sbcl.core-for-slime")
```

After that, add something like this to your ‘.emacs’:

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
’((sbcl ("sbcl" "--core" "sbcl.core-for-slime"))))"
```

I know how to add stuff to my .emacs file but what exactly do i do for the part below i\e where, exactly, and how do i execute the steps below....i\e where do i type it.
"execute the following steps:

```
shell$ sbcl
* (mapc ’require ’(sb-bsd-sockets sb-posix sb-introspect sb-cltl2 asdf))
* (save-lisp-and-die "sbcl.core-for-slime")"
```

please be specific ...I'm a noob

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to add stuff to my .emacs file but what exactly do i do for
>   the part below i\e where, exactly, and how do i execute the steps
>   below....i\e where do i type it. "execute the following steps:

You start up your Lisp implementation in a shell, and enter in its REPL. While Slime is a Common Lisp (and a few languages more) environment for Emacs, the actual CL implementation is not included or part of Emacs. (Emacs itself uses a somewhat similar but different dialect, Emacs Lisp.)

So, you have to install SBCL separately, start it, and then enter the commands above in its REPL.

```
(mapc #'require '(sb-bsd-sockets sb-posix sb-introspect sb-cltl2 asdf))
```

Note that you have to use `'`, not `’` for it to work. This will load the systems in your Lisp image, and:

```
(save-lisp-and-die "sbcl.core-for-slime")
```

will save that image into the file `sbcl.core-for-slime`. When you tell SBCL to use that image (also called *core* image), you won't have to load the above systems again, because they are already part of the loaded image. That's what the

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      '((sbcl ("sbcl" "--core" "sbcl.core-for-slime"))))
```

in your `.emacs` does – it tells SLIME to use the command `sbcl --core sbcl.core-for-slime` when starting SBCL.

Also note, that *Common Lisp* is the name of the language, while *CLISP* is just an implementation, like SBCL. I'll retag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Shell is a command-line interface to your computer.  In Emacs, you may get to a shell by entering <kbd>M-x</kbd>`shell` (ie., pressing these keys in sequence: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>).  A new window will come up, and in it a shell prompt waiting for your input.  Enter `sbcl` at the prompt to start SBCL; you may then enter the lisp code snippets to create a new core.

For the above to work, you have to have SBCL installed first (eg, by following the instructions at [www.sbcl.org](http://www.sbcl.org)).